# Firebase does not Remember Auth on iOS added to HomeScreen

Tags: firebase

Firebase does remember and auto-login when I visit the site on mobile safari. However, when I add the app to iOS home screen, it does not seem to auto login anymore.

Home screen apps may clear cookies each time on load.

Is there anyway to get it to auto login as a homescreen app?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

[Engineer at Firebase] Note that [Firebase Simple Login](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-overview.html) is a separate service built on top of [Firebase Authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/authentication.html), intended to simplify authenticating users and generating Firebase Auth. Tokens for use in [Security Rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/security-rules.html).

**Update 2014/03/07**: Support for redirect-based OAuth has been added to the Firebase Simple Login Web Client as of v1.3.0, available from the [Firebase CDN](https://www.firebase.com/docs/downloads.html) or via Bower using `bower install firebase-simple-login`. This update enables the Simple Login client to automatically detect iOS "standalone" applications and handle the redirect-based OAuth automatically.

<strike>There is an existing bug at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login/issues/7 to add support for a redirect-based authentication flow, which is required to support iOS standalone-webview apps.</strike>

Comment: Does simple email-password use a redirect-based flow? That is what I am currently using (:

Comment: @ddhhz Currently, nothing uses a redirect-based flow, but (soon) it will be added for OAuth-providers only. Can you provide code for a repro case for your issue, or file it as a separate task on the GitHub repo?